# Compiler error:C3861 'GetModuleHandleEx': identifier not found

Tags: winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void * _ReturnAddress(void);

#pragma intrinsic(_ReturnAddress)
//I inserted the following code inside one of the functions

void func()
{
------------
-------
----
-
    HMODULE module_handle;
    TCHAR module_name[4096];
    DWORD flag = 0x00000004;

    GetModuleHandleEx(flag, (LPCTSTR) _ReturnAddress(), &module_handle);

    GetModuleFileName(module_handle,module_name,4096);

-----
--
}
```

When I compile the code as a separate project everything works fine. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To compile an application that uses
>   this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as
>   0x0501 or later. For more information,
>   see [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you please provide your reference

Comment: Straight from the MSDN Library article.

Comment: We're here to help you find it back.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get your code to compile, what you're doing smells of wrongness.

If you're using the return address to make any sort of security-related decision, **stop**.  [You can't trust the return address of the calling function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/01/47042.aspx).  No really, [**you can't trust the return address of the calling function**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/17/704232.aspx).